# Problem with Advanced Filter in VBA macro: text column with data like date format

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic table with a column formatted as 'text' containing:

```
ID
575/23
100/268
45/20
05/19
4574/89
07/23
04/2021
```

Note that many of them are similar to dates: '05/19', '07/23' and '04/2021'.

If I apply an advanced filter (with a same named field in other table), I get correctly all the data, but if I do the same by recording a macro and assigning it to a form button, when I click the button it doesn't get certain values that can be interpreted as date.

The generated macro code is:

```
    Range("the_data").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("the_filter"), _
        CopyToRange:=Range("the_result"), _
        Unique:=False
```

It doesn't get the '05/19' and '07/23' values (I suppose the are interpreted as date, but the field is text format in both tables)... but It returns '04/2021' correctly...

I hope anybody can help, I spent many hours!

Comment: Note that format and the underlying value are separate things. A date is a formatted number. Possibly there's a mismatch between `Range("the_data")` and `Range("the_filter")`, where one of them has  date(s) and the other has text-that-looks-like-a-date.

Comment: Nope, I have checked it: all cells in the column of each table are formated as text.

As I said, the filter applies correctly when doing manually, but not when the macro is called.

Comment: Hmm I may be able to reproduce, investigating further.

Comment: Pls provide the criteria range

Comment: Thanks @rotabor and BigBen !  

  **Sheet1** (A1:A8 - 'the data' with the data I put in my first message).  

  **Sheet2** (A1:A8 - 'the filter' with same data).  

  **Sheet3** (A1 - 'the result') : select this sheet before go to Data > Advanced in order to put the result here (by recording the macro) not in sheet2.  

PD: Sorry, I put two spaces but no linebreaks are inserted.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue in Excel 365. So, I formatted A1:A8 as text first, then put values there, then copied this range to the second sheet. The manual advanced filter and macro work the same - all values are copied to the_result. Pls. be aware that Excel behaves differently depending on what you did first - put values or formatted cells.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rotabor, but please, notice I said it works always when I do the advanced filter manually: the problem is only when I assign the macro to a form button and click it.

Comment: All table cells in both tables are formatted as Text.

Comment: @JavierM In the VBA Editor Immediate Window, what do you see if you type`?Worksheets("Sheet2").range("A4").value2` and then hit `<Return>`? (*Note the leading `?`*)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld with A4 I get 45/20, I tried with A5 I get 05/19 and with A7 I get 07/23 thanks

Comment: If I apply the text formatting to the cells again, a small green check mark is displayed at the top left of the cells with the values '05/19' and '07/23' and a yellow triangle is displayed on the right, and when you placed the cursor over it the message "This cell contains a date string represented with only 2 digits for the year" is displayed.

After clicking on the triangle I have tried ignoring the error and other options, but I cannot get all the results to be displayed when applying the advanced filter with the button (doing it manually does work).

Comment: @JavierM I cannot reproduce your problem using your data, code and named ranges. There's something else going on. Do you get the same values for `Value2` if you specify `"Sheet1"`?

Comment: Thanks anyway @RonRosenfeld , I get the same results in the Inmediate panel with Sheet1 and Sheet2. I have no 365 subscription, I tried with Excel 2021 and Excel 2020 in two computers with same result.

Comment: @JavierM Can you share a workbook?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld [1]: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/dn6rivr5yqps7g1zbllfz/excel_advanced_filter.xlsm?rlkey=padrjbjxkn57hwpeymop6a9yd&dl=0

Comment: @JavierM I only have `365` (Windows version) and your macro seems to work without any issues. I downloaded the file; saved a copy (to enable macros), opened the copy; pushed the "button", and all the entries showed up on Sheet3.  I am out of ideas. Can you get it to malfunction using Excel on the web?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It's good to know, with 2019 and 2021 failed at work and home computers. I have not subscription at this time but I will try (the free Office web version doesn't support macros). Thanks a lot for your help !